# NSOrderedSet response from server and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to show data as it came from the backend So let's have an example json file:

```
{
  "fonts": [
    {
      "name": "Helvetica",
      "styleIdentifier": "H0",
      "size": 17
    },
    {
      "name": "Helvetica",
      "styleIdentifier": "H1",
      "size": 14
    },
    {
      "name": "Helvetica-Bold",
      "styleIdentifier": "H0Bold",
      "size": 17
    },
    {
      "name": "HelveticaNeue-Light",
      "styleIdentifier": "H0Light",
      "size": 40
    }
  ]
}
```

So i create a `relationship` (many - many) with `ordered` option selected. And by the input i see it's always write in the same way to Core Data, but when I try to fetch it

`configuratation.fonts` where `fonts` is a `NSOrderedSet` i get items in completly random order. I miss sth in spec? Or I should sort it somehow?

**__EDIT__**

Firstly when i get a data from above json I have a configuration set with empty font relation. Then I fetch this and insert it into core data with:

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSDictionary *fontDictionary in jsonArray) {
    Font *fontObj = [Font font:fontDictionary inContext:context];
    [returnArray addObject:fontObj];
}
```

And in this array data is in correct order. Then in configuration object i add it to `NSOrderedSet` by:

```
-(void)appendTracks:(NSArray<Font*>*)fontArray {
    self.fonts = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray: fontArray];
}
```

And then i try to fetch it by simply use reference:

```
configuration.fonts
```

And in this step data are completly not in correct order.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are fetching the data when you get it in the wrong order.

Comment: I added both - input and output data

Comment: I dont get it then - if i need additional attribute whats the difference in core data between NSSet and NSOrderedSet?

Comment: If you put breakpoint at append track and use po [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray: fontArray]; are the order wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the `Ordered` checkbox for the relationship in the DataModel?

Comment: Yes, it's checked and @NikoAdrianusYuwono no - there it's correct order

Comment: What's the type of the `fonts` property?

Comment: It's relationship so NSOrderedSet

Comment: Is it set to NSOrderedSet in the CoreData autogenerated extension, too, or do you make that assumption based on what you see in the datamodel-file?

Comment: Yes it's in generated file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127166/discussion-between-jan-nash-and-kuba).

Comment: add order field to models on backend and forget about this kind of troubles

Comment: If you're working with 3rd party API it's not that easy... @sage444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set the NSOrderedSet directly.

Either modify the existing set:

```
[self.fonts addObjectsFromArray:fontArray];
```

Or:

Xcode generates methods to add and remove entries from ordered sets within the generated `NSManagedObject` class.

Assuming you have an `Entity` called `ManagedConfiguration` which holds an ordered to many relation called `fonts`:

```
ManagedConfiguration *managedObjectConfigurationInstance = //create or fetch configuration in ManagedObjectContext
NSOrderedSet<ManagedFont> *fonts = //created or fetched fonts in wanted order
managedObjectConfigurationInstance.addToFonts(fonts)
```

`replaceFonts`, `removeFromFontsAtIndex` aso. methods are also generated.

---

Depending on your requirements, you might want to store the fonts in random order and apply a `NSSortDescriptor` to your `NSFetchRequest` to fetch the data in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to set the data directly to your property(`fonts`), you need to first fetch the mutable copy of your `NSOrderedSet` from the `NSmanagedObject` Subclass (I assume it to be `Font`).

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *orderedSet = [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"fonts"];
```

Then add the objects from the array to this orderedSet.

```
[orderedSet addObjectsFromArray:array];
```

Now you would have properly set the the values for the key `fonts`.
So your `appendTracks` function would now look like this.

```
-(void)appendTracks:(NSArray<Font*>*)fontArray {
    NSMutableOrderedSet *orderedSet = [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"fonts"];
    [orderedSet addObjectsFromArray:fontArray];
}
```

Now execute your fetch request. You should receive the data in the set order in the array.

PS:I had used your JSON response to test this.